# filtering a string in c

Tags: c

Given the input ~Zw~~"iE^L I should get !w~"iE^L instead I am getting Zw~"iE^L

So it catch the ~~ just fine and replace it with ~ but I want to replace ~Z with !

Any ideas?

```
  for (j = 0; j < dataCharCount; j++, k++)
  {
    if (inputData[j] == '~' && inputData[j + 1] == '~')
    {
      filteredInputData[k] = '~';
      j++;
    }
    else if (inputData[j] == '~' && inputData[j + 1] == 'Z')
    {
      filteredInputData[k] = '!';
      j++;

    }
    filteredInputData[k] = inputData[j];
  }
```

Comment: you could have found the problem by using your debugger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
} else {
    filteredInputData[k] = inputData[j];
}
```

Without the else you're overwriting `filteredInputData[k]` after the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

there is an `else` missing before the last ine of the function. you surely do not want to copy the input to the output (`filteredInputData[k] = inputData[j];`) after having performed the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The last statement in your loop overwrites the `~` or `!` you wrote via your `if` statment body.  The reason it looks like it works for the `~~` is that it's overwriting the `~` with another `~`.  In the `~Z` case, you're overwriting your `!` with the `Z`.  Step through your code with a debugger - you'll see what's happening immediately.